# Modal popup jquery not closing second time

Tags: jquery, razor, modal-dialog

I have created a simple change password screen, for this, I have created a partial view and whenever the "Change Password" link will be clicked, partial view will load as jquery modal dialog. Everything is working except 2 things.

1. first time close button closes the modal dialog but second time it
   doesn't.
2. I have a confirmMessage div to show an error and success
   message. Lets say after successful operation I have to show the
   confirmation message for 5 sec then close the model dialog, which I
   am not able to figure out how to do.

Anyone's help will be appreciated. Below is my code.

------Partial View -----

```
    <div id="cPassword" style="display:none;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "changePwd" }))
    {   <center>
            <div id="confirmMessage" class="hidden"></div>
        </center>
        <br />

        <label for="OldPasswordL">Old Password:</label>
        <div>@Html.Password("OldPassword")</div>
        <div>
            <label id="OldPasswordV" class="hidden">Old password is required.</label>
        </div>

        <label for="NewPasswordL">New Password:</label>
        <div>@Html.Password("NewPassword")</div>
        <div>
            <label id="NewPasswordV" class="hidden">New password is required.</label>
        </div>

        <label for="ConfirmNewPasswordL">Confirm New Password:</label>
        <div>@Html.Password("ConfirmNewPassword")</div>
        <div>
            <label id="ConfirmNewPasswordV" class="hidden">Confirm password is required.</label>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Close" id="btnClose" />
        </div>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cPassword").dialog({
            create: function (event, ui) {
                $("body").css({ overflow: 'hidden' })
            },
            modal: true,
            title: ": : Change Password : :"
        });

        $('#btnClose').click(function () {
            $('#cPassword').dialog('close');
        });

        $('#ConfirmMessage').hide();


        $('#OldPassword').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#OldPassword').val().length == 0) {
                $('#OldPasswordV').addClass('visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#OldPasswordV').removeClass('visible');
                $('#OldPasswordV').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        $('#NewPassword').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#NewPassword').val().length == 0) {
                $('#NewPasswordV').addClass('visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#NewPasswordV').removeClass('visible');
                $('#NewPasswordV').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });


        $('#ConfirmNewPassword').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#ConfirmNewPassword').val().length == 0) {
                $('#ConfirmNewPasswordV').addClass('visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#ConfirmNewPasswordV').removeClass('visible');
                $('#ConfirmNewPasswordV').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });

        $('#ConfirmNewPassword').blur(function () {
            comparePassword();
        });


        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            if ($('#OldPassword').val().length == 0) {
                $('#OldPasswordV').addClass('visible');
                return false;
            }
            if ($('#NewPassword').val().length == 0) {
                $('#NewPasswordV').addClass('visible');
                return false;
            }
            if ($('#ConfirmNewPassword').val().length == 0) {
                $('#ConfirmNewPasswordV').addClass('visible');
                return false;
            }
            if (comparePassword() == true) {
                $.post("User/changePassword", $('#changePwd').serialize(), function (data) {
                    $("#confirmMessage").show().delay(5000).queue(function (n) {
                        $('#cPassword').dialog('close');
                    });
                });
            }
        });


        function comparePassword() {
            if ($('#ConfirmNewPassword').val() != $('#NewPassword').val()) {
                $('#confirmMessage').addClass('visible');
                $('#confirmMessage').text('Passwords are not same.');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#confirmMessage').removeClass('visible');
                $('#confirmMessage').addClass('hidden');
                $('#confirmMessage').text('');
                return true;
            }
        }


    });
</script>
```

------Controller------

```
public ActionResult changePassword()
    {
        return PartialView("_changePassword");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using update panel?

Comment: 1. Please, show the code that opens the dialog ("Change Password" link handler).

Comment: 2. Use JS setTimeout function

Comment: Below is the code which opens the modal dialog

@Ajax.ActionLink("Change Password","changePassword", "User",new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv"})

<div id="partialDiv"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that opens the Change Password dialog

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Change Password","changePassword", "User",new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv"})

<div id="partialDiv"></div>
```